# Perforce Restore From Multiple Checkpoint Files?

Tags: restore, files, perforce

I am working with a very large (~11GB) checkpoint file and trying to do a -jr (journal restore) operation.  About half way through the file, I'm hitting an entry which causes an error to occur.  I'm unable to come up with a conventional way to print, edit, and save changes to the offending line.

So right now I'm splitting the checkpoint into files of 500k lines each...up to 47 files and counting.  My question is, once I have these separate files:

1. Can I run journal restore on each one separately to check for errors?
2. Once fixed, is it necessary to merge them back together again to do my full journal restore?

Any other ideas on how to tackle this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

-aj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when we hit snags like this, we run the question by support@perforce.com. They have pretty fast turnaround time.

They do a great job of helping users through manual checkpoint surgery.